# Opening a Form when a Particular Form has been opened before

Tags: vb.net-2010

Given FormA and FormB, I want my code to run so that FormB will only run if FormA has been opened before. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you paste your code what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could put in the main form some "global" var. On the LOAD of FormA change that value. Check the value for the FormB.

MainForm

```
Dim FormAOpened As Boolean = false

Public Sub setFormAOpened()
   FormAOpened = true
End SubF
   return    FormAOpened
End Function
```

FormA

```
Public Function FormA_OnLoad(...)
MainForm.setFormAOpened()
...
End Function
```

FormB

```
If (MainForm.getFormAOpened) Then
...
Else
```